# www server restart after upgrading bash regarding the shell shock bug?

Tags: bash, cgi

If a webserver uses CGI with bash, does it calls bash every time when there is a request regarding CGI or does it caches (bash and related libraries) it when starting the webserver?

**Q:** So is a webserver restart needed after upgrading the bash packge regarding the shell shock bug?

UPDATE:

https://access.redhat.com/articles/1200223

```
"Services that create such environment variables will need to be restarted to work with the new version of Bash. This behavior is not used by any of the packages provided in any version of Red Hat Enterprise Linux."
```

But later they write:

```
Do I need to reboot or restart services after installing this update?
No, a reboot of your system or any of your services is not required.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you're making use of Bash scripts as CGI via your webserver a new process is forked every time that CGI is executed. The same is typically the case with Perl & Python scripts as well.

You'll typically see additional technologies that are part of the webserver (I'm talking Apache specifically here) where they'll invoke a single instance of the "interpreter" and then pipe the various scripts into the running "interpreter" or they'll compile the CGI into a runnable object that will persist within memory until the server is either restarted, or the persisting layer is instructed to drop these objects from memory.

So if they're the Bash variety, no restart should be required, especially if the CGI scripts are written with a `#!/bin/bash` at the top for the shebang.